# how to use cat (text file) command with sed

Tags: shell, unix

i have the below file

cat index.txt

```
<table border="0">
<TR><TH>FULL DEPLOYMENT</TH></TR>
<TR bgcolor="#E2EBF8">
<TD>nv Name</TD>
<TD>Source Branch</TD>
TR bgcolor="#EEEEEE"></TD> <TD>master_SDP_BIL</TD> 
<TD>2018/02/18_16:37:14</TD> <TD></TD> <TD>testing</TD> 
<TD>mymail@gmail.com</TD>
```

in another file :
cat findex.txt

cat findex.txt

```
<TD bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD 
  bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD>
```

i want to add the content of findex.txt to index.txt after

```
<TD>mymail@gmail.com</TD>
```

so final file will be:

```
<table border="0">
<TR><TH>FULL DEPLOYMENT</TH></TR>
<TR bgcolor="#E2EBF8">
<TD>Env Name</TD>
<TR bgcolor="#EEEEEE"></TD> <TD>master_SDP_BIL</TD> 
<TD>2018/02/18_16:37:14</TD> <TD></TD> <TD>testing</TD> 
<TD>mymail@gmail.com</TD> <TD bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD 
 bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> <TD 
 bgcolor=#00EE00>OK</TD> </TR>
 </table>
```

im using below command but it's adding index.txt instead of contect

```
sed -i 's/\@gmail.com</TD>\/"cat $(findex.txt)"/g' index.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'read' command:

```
sed -i '/<TD>mymail@gmail.com<\/TD>/r findex.txt' index.txt
```